# Reports from SQL Server using Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, data-warehouse

I've developed an intranet system for our company which uses a SQL Server 2008 backend.  This stores an awful lot of information and I'm frequently asked to build reports for various managers to help with the business.  Quite often these reports are variations on a theme, whilst sometimes they're quite unique.  At the moment I write SQL to perform the report and have them dump the required output via ASP.Net pages.  What I'd really like to do is get away from that, and I was thinking along the lines of having the managers query the database using Excel so that they can decide what fields to filter on etc.  To this end I wrote a couple of views and used Excel to connect to them.  The problem is that without filtering you end up with a lot of data, so I was wondering about the best way to approach this.  I've not had anything to do with data warehousing/Analysis Services but I wondered if that was a route to look at, or should I be looking at Reporting Services? I've got access to the full Microsoft stack so happy to use different solutions

I'm more then happy to spend some time doing some reading/research but I'm a bit unsure where to begin so any pointers would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: 2007 but I could get that changed if there's some 'new' feature that'd make this task easier/more efficient.

Comment: Well powerpivot is what you're looking for. Its an addin for 2010, and built in to 2013, where you really get to exploit some cool features. have a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woiFeD7zf8A)

Comment: What the video doesn't show, is that through using this you can create pivot tables using the relationship model built into your server, pulling different fields from multiple tables, and it's pretty quick - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4QNj0lIPPI&list=PL0CB09E9526E50B80&index=1

Comment: Can you not build the necessary logic into your views to implement an initial layer of filters?

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services offers pretty good integration with Excel. You should take a look at it.